# modify wordpress default search

Tags: plugin-development, search

I would like to modify WordPress default search.

I have 2 questions: which template file to modify, and how can I include posts ids that I want to include in search?

I need to search from specific post ids, so I want to modify search in this particular way.

Comment: There is a whole page of information at the WP Codex on [Creating a Search Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of search results is controlled by `search.php` template (or generic `index.php` if it's not present).

And search is technically a usual WordPress loop with `s` query argument, so any snippets that apply to loops can be used to tweak search.